Selenium Explicit wait not proceeding to the next steps even when the specified conditions are met
We have encountered a problem with Explicit wait conditions in Selenium. We are currently utilizing Selenium version 4.19 / 4.20 with C# .NET 4.7.2. Recently, we noticed that when using Explicit wait conditions such as ElementisVisible or ElementToBeClickable, Selenium does not proceed to the next steps even when the specified conditions are met before the allotted time. Instead, Selenium waits until the maximum specified time for the explicit wait.
We have recently revised our code based on Selenium's "Waiting Strategies" documentation
Previously we are using following code:
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("id")));

Recently, refactored the new code
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(d => revealed.Displayed);

a. In both situations, it behaves identically. According to Selenium documentation on wait conditions, it is stated that using both implicit and explicit waits concurrently in the same driver may lead to improper functionality.

We employ an implicit wait of 10 seconds, while the explicit wait varies from 10 to 30 seconds depending on the application's behavior.
Could this issue be due to our framework employing both implicit and explicit waits? Selenium waits for the maximum specified time for all explicit conditions, causing a significant increase in execution time. Can someone please assist in resolving this issue?
b. While working with the new wait conditions code using lambda expressions only for "Displayed," I have not been able to locate equivalent wait conditions for other explicit wait conditions in Selenium. (like InvisibilityOfElementLocated, ElementToBeClickable, etc..)
